# html2canvas creates a canvas with a width and height of zero?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html2canvas

I'm trying to use html2canvas do what it says on the tin, but it keeps creating a canvas with a width and height of zero.
I'm doing this:

```
var HTMLString = '<p>hello world</p>';
var HTMLStringContainer = document.createElement('div');
HTMLStringContainer.innerHTML = HTMLString;
console.log(HTMLStringContainer);
html2canvas(HTMLStringContainer,{
    onrendered:function(newCanvas){
        document.getElementById("image").appendChild(newCanvas);
    }
});
```

And when I print `HTMLStringContainer` it shows `<div><p>hello world</p></div>`, which looks correct.

### Snippet

```js
var HTMLString = '<p>hello world</p>';
var HTMLStringContainer = document.createElement('div');
HTMLStringContainer.innerHTML = HTMLString;
console.log(HTMLStringContainer);
html2canvas(HTMLStringContainer, {
  onrendered: function(newCanvas) {
    document.getElementById("image").appendChild(newCanvas);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/releases/download/0.4.1/html2canvas.js"></script>
<div id="image"></div>
```

Also, jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/4077wxLj/

Comment: It looks like for `html2canvas` to render, it needs to be *in the document* (like, a child of `document.body`)

Comment: `html2canvas` needs to be in the document, or the canvas it creates needs to be in the document?

Comment: No the first. Try doing `document.body.appendChild(HTMLStringContainer)`. It should work.

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/prankol57/3k4rngfL/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The element to render as a canvas needs to be in the DOM, such as a child of `document.body`, before it can be rendered.