# Rendering html string to canvas without showing the html itself

Tags: javascript, html, html2canvas

I would like to convert an html string to image similar to how it's done here:
[html2canvas creates a canvas with a width and height of zero?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27493672/html2canvas-creates-a-canvas-with-a-width-and-height-of-zero)

However I don't want to show anything other than result image on the page. Thus I can't simply add the html string to the DOM as suggested there. I assume what I'm trying to achieve is possible because [html2canvas test console](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/screenshots.html) does just that.

I tried the following which produces empty result:

```js
var doc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument();
doc.open();
doc.write("<html><header></header><body><div>test</div></body></html>");
doc.close();

html2canvas(doc.body, {
    onrendered:function(newCanvas) {
        document.body.appendChild(newCanvas);
    }    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/blob/master/dist/html2canvas.js"></script>
```

Can anyone suggest the way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured that out. Here is [the link](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/196) which headed me to the right direction. It is also worth checking the source code of [this page](http://www.fritz-elfert.de/h2c.html?ModPagespeed=off) which illustrates the idea.

We set the

```
style="overflow:hidden"
```

attribute for the container and move the contents we want to render outside of the viewport with

```
style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:3000px;"
```

Hope that helps someone.